# Django url template tag output

Tags: django-templates, django-urls

I'm doing a navbar in django and in the links I' need an output like this: "/category/1/", "/category/2/", "/category/3/", what is the method to do this in urls templete tags?

I already made: {% url 'my_app:category' category.id=1 %} not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, finally I' did this:

```
<ul> 
{% for category in categories%}
<li><a href="{% url 'myapp:categories' category.id %}">{{category}}</a></li>
</ul>
{% empty%}
<li>Empty!</li>
{% endfor%
```

that worked for me.